# Further customize Return value using MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have the following unit test.

```
[TestMethod]    
    public void IfTheSecondPaymentFailsThenTheFirstPaymentShouldBeVoided()
    {
        var iPaymentMock = new Mock<IPaymentMock>();
        var paymentSpecificationResponse = new PreregisteredAccountSpec();   
        iPaymentMock.Setup(
                counter => counter.ProcessPayment
                    (
                        It.IsAny<Context>(),
                        It.IsAny<PreregisteredAccountSpec>(),  
                        It.IsAny<Guid>())
                    ).
                 Returns((Context context, PaymentSpecification spec, Guid guid) =>
                {
                    return paymentSpecificationResponse;
                }
                );
    }
```

How can I change the test to return paymentSpecificationResponse.Distributions[0].Transaction.GetVendorId() as "1" when the Distributions array is read only.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the mock return value based on the parameters passed to it. You can use an overload of `.Returns()` and provide a function.

```
.Returns((context, spec, guid) => { //Do something with the arguments passed to the mock })
```

Comment: I guess my question should have been : how should I change the paymentSpecificationResponse when I cannot "set" paymentSpecificationResponse.Distributions[0]?  The paymentSpecificationResponse is part of a third party dll.

Comment: I understand now. Unfortunately, without being able to see the third party classes, it's hard to give a definitive answer. Is there a `SetVendorId()` function you can call? Can you set `.Transaction` to a mock?

Comment: In fact, they had a a AddDistribution method to add a distribution. Creating a valid distribution and adding it using the AddDistribution method worked for me.